# Get list of users with name, phone number and group memberships from G Suite

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I have looked into the G Suite admin APIs and found this function:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users

I get a list of all users, but no users in the list have a phone number. How can I include the user's phone number in the list?

I would also like to know how to get a list of every user's group memberships if this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phone number property is under **user Resource** which you might have missed since it's also located in the [Users.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) under Response.

```
  {
  "kind": "admin#directory#users",
  "etag": etag,
  "users": [
    users Resource
  ],
  "nextPageToken": string
}
```

which when you click leads to the full [User Resources](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users#resource) which then contains the `phones` property including others.

```
"phones": [
    {
      "value": string,
      "primary": boolean,
      "type": string,
      "customType": string
    }
  ],
  "phones": string
```